# how to update label value from jquery modal popup in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, findcontrol

I have a page, product.aspx.  Inside this page I have a label that shows the count of products added to basket.  I also have viewcart.aspx page to show my cart item and edit or delete product.

Everything is well but when I delete a product from viewcart.aspx, I want to decrement the label value on product.aspx.  How can I do that?

I use this jQuery to show viewcart.aspx on modal popup:
`http://deseloper.org/examples/simple-modal-redux/`

also I've tried to use

`Label lbl = (Label)this.PreviousPage.FindControl("countlbl");`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the viewcart.aspx page, you could add some jQuery to fire when it closes (i.e. on the onUnload event):

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  window.opener.$("#product_count_label").html("new count of products");
});
```

Comment: ken.. lok this Url   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237009/problem-sending-value-from-jquery-modal-popup-to-parent

Comment: it solved here  http://forums.asp.net/t/1686861.aspx/1?problem+sending+value+from+jquery+modal+popup+to+parent